# Image Appear upon Scrolling down Page | Sharepoint Online Embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-online

I have embeded the following code onto my sharepoint online site. The image appears in the bottom right hand corner and once clicked it takes me to the top of the page, as coded; however the Jquery javascript code doesn't appear to work... The image just stays visible regardless of how many pixels are scrolled.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"><\script>
<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>100) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="toTop">
<a style="position: fixed; bottom:20px;left:5px;" href="#ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" title="Back to Top"><img style="border: none; height: 37.5px; width:50.5px" src="backtotop-1.png" ></a>
</div>
```

The above code encompasses both suggested solutions and still doesn't appear to work! The image is visible regardless of how much the page is scrolled, yet once clicked the image disappears. The code appears to work completely fine in a plain .html file.

Please help! Thank you very much in advance.

Current Console Error:

[image: Google Chrome Console Error]

Answer (score 1):

yeah, its your jquery source. have u seen a "space" in jquery src line, also you forget to close the  tag. and for future dont forget to check the browser console for errors.

you can use the following fixed code in your source file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>100) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
</script>
<style>
body{
  border: 1px dotted red;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
</style>
<div id="toTop">
<a style="position: fixed; bottom:20px;left:5px;" href="#ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" title="Back to Top">
  <img style="border:1px solid red; height: 37px; width:50px" src="https://i.imgur.com/WkCCy7L.jpg" >
</a>
</div>
```

let me know if this fixes your error now.

Comment: Made the changes as requested, updated JQuery version, still not working - Please see code above. Console showed that http:// rrequest for the script was being denied, so I updated it to HTTPS and no console error regarding that, but still no luck!

Comment: Hi, upon using your code the image still appears on the page regardless of how far you scroll; however, once the image is clicked, the image fades out. It's almost like the addition of #ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2 to the URL dictates the fade-out rather than the scrolling of the page. Any ideas what could be causing this? Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: okay, so we still have the issue. can u post link to your site, where you are trying to do this. if not possible, can u give a reference site like one with functionality you want to copy?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you a link to the website due to company rules. I can see that when I enter the code into a .html file the code works as it should and therefore must be something to do with me using SHAREPOINT ONLINE as the website hosting tool. I have noticed console errors have appeared, which is most likely what is causing the issues. Please see the image appended at the bottom of my question above^ Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PythonBen sorry buddy, these are lots n lots of error, in most cases javascript stops working even if 1 error is encountered. in your case these seem neverending. also as u confirmed the code is working fine out of your website than i am afraid no 1 here can help you without actually removing each line of error in that console pic. and if your website is on internet, than i dont see any problem in sharing link, still you can send me the website link in Private Message if you want. see ya

Answer (score 1):

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5q2pw1n/) link of your code. It works perfectly well. You just need to check the below line if the *jquery 1.6.4.min.js*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery 1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

This should be the right one: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

Comment: I've added the version suggested - Still not working, please see new code above.